# Displaying in-memory GeoJSON in ArcGIS API for JavaScript

Tags: geojson, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, azure

Right now I have a GeoJSON hosted on Azure so I can download it by URL like so:

```
const geojsonLayer = new GeoJSONLayer({
 url: "www.url.from.azure.com,
 copyright: "USGS Earthquakes",
 popupTemplate: template
});
```

But it is quite big (~30 MB) and takes a while to load, so what I am trying to do is host it on Azure as a .zip file, download it, and then parse it into JSON. What I then want to do is feed it into the GeoJSONLayer so I can then display it. Is there anyway to do this?

I already have the download a zip file, unzip and parse as a JSON function ready so it would just be displaying the parsed JSON object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take advantage of [createObjectURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) to create a URL object that you can set the GeoJSONLayer.url parameter to.

```
  function createGeoJSONURL(yourgeojson) {
    return URL.createObjectURL(
      new Blob([JSON.stringify(yourgeojson)], {
        type: "application/json"
      })
    );
  }
```